# KEA dhcp Mysql Backend

Tags: mysql, dhcp

I have an issue with the new ISC DHCP, KEA, on the MySQL backend.
I want to store leases in my DB, it works but some info are not stored.

I obtain this kind of entry in my DB :

```
+------------+--------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+                
| address    | hwaddr | client_id | valid_lifetime | expire              | subnet_id | fqdn_fwd | fqdn_rev | hostname |              
+------------+--------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 3232236052 | '°     | NULL      |           4000 | 2015-07-22 08:54:32 |         1 |        0 |        0 |          │                 
+------------+--------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

The address field is the IP adress in decimal, I checked and it's the good one. 
I didn't find how change the IP adress to IPv4 format and how store mac address in the hwaddr field in the KEA documentation.

If someone know how to do this I will be really grateful !

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per KEA documentation `hwaddr` field is `VARBINARY`. You should be able to see the value IP address and hwaddr using:

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(address), HEX(hwaddr), lease4.* FROM lease4;
```

Comment: it works, I can see my IP address and hwaddr ! Thank you ! But I would like to have these values in my DB, do you have an idea to force KEA to store these data directly to these format ? it is even possible ? And can you share me the link where you found the type of the datas ? Thank you again !

Comment: @MaxGeneGrim, you can find [dhcpdb_create.mysql](https://github.com/isc-projects/kea/blob/master/src/bin/admin/scripts/mysql/dhcpdb_create.mysql) script in the Kea package. Don't know how to change the way information is stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need to create KEA host reservations and populate the MAC and IP addresses as regular strings while still having the fields KEA uses updated automatically on an INSERT or UPDATE.

What I ended up doing is creating two new fields that would hold those string values ('hosts.dhcp_identifier_str' and 'hosts.ipv4_address_str'):

```
ALTER TABLE `hosts` ADD `dhcp_identifier_str` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL AFTER `dhcp_identifier`;
ALTER TABLE `hosts` ADD `ipv4_address_str` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `ipv4_address`;
```

Then, I keep the corresponding fields that KEA uses ('hosts.dhcp_identifier' and 'hosts.ipv4_address') up to date by using BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE MySQL triggers:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `host_BINS`//
CREATE TRIGGER `host_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `hosts`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF (NEW.dhcp_identifier = '' AND NEW.dhcp_identifier_str != '') THEN
          SET NEW.dhcp_identifier = UNHEX(UPPER(NEW.dhcp_identifier_str));
ELSEIF (NEW.dhcp_identifier_str = '' AND NEW.dhcp_identifier != '') THEN
          SET NEW.dhcp_identifier_str = LOWER(HEX(NEW.dhcp_identifier));
END IF;

IF (NEW.ipv4_address IS NULL AND NEW.ipv4_address_str IS NOT NULL) THEN
          SET NEW.ipv4_address = INET_ATON(NEW.ipv4_address_str);
ELSEIF (NEW.ipv4_address_str IS NULL AND NEW.ipv4_address IS NOT NULL) THEN
          SET NEW.ipv4_address_str = CAST(INET_NTOA(NEW.ipv4_address) AS CHAR);
END IF;
END
//

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `host_BUPD`//
CREATE TRIGGER `host_BUPD` BEFORE UPDATE ON `hosts`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF (NEW.dhcp_identifier_str != '' AND OLD.dhcp_identifier != UNHEX(UPPER(NEW.dhcp_identifier_str))) THEN
          SET NEW.dhcp_identifier = UNHEX(UPPER(NEW.dhcp_identifier_str));
ELSEIF (NEW.dhcp_identifier != '' AND OLD.dhcp_identifier_str != LOWER(HEX(NEW.dhcp_identifier))) THEN
          SET NEW.dhcp_identifier_str = LOWER(HEX(NEW.dhcp_identifier));
END IF;

IF (NEW.ipv4_address_str IS NOT NULL AND OLD.ipv4_address != INET_ATON(NEW.ipv4_address_str)) THEN
          SET NEW.ipv4_address = INET_ATON(NEW.ipv4_address_str);
ELSEIF (NEW.ipv4_address IS NOT NULL AND OLD.ipv4_address_str != CAST(INET_NTOA(NEW.ipv4_address) AS CHAR)) THEN
          SET NEW.ipv4_address_str = CAST(INET_NTOA(NEW.ipv4_address) AS CHAR);
END IF;
END
//
```

This works whether you INSERT/UPDATE an entry using the dhcp_identifier/ipv4_address or dhcp_identifier_str/ipv4_address_str pairs.

I'm sure you can use the same triggers for the 'lease4' table.

Hope that helps.